# Sitefinity and The database schema version is higher than the running Sitefinity version. Downgrade is not allowed

Tags: sitefinity

Has anyone come across a situation where they are unable to start a Sitefinity site due to this error

```
The database schema version (6421) is higher than the running Sitefinity version (6410). Downgrade is not allowed
```

I've searched for a decent answer but I haven't been able to find one yet. Any help would be good.

Answer (score 3):

It means that you ran build 6421 on this database (and possibly upgaded it). Now you are trying to run a lower build 6410, which is not allowed by default.
You can override this behavior by setting `ignoreDowngradeExceptions="true"` on the connection string, although you should be careful with using this approach on a production environment. 
In case of these two builds, overriding the default behavior will most probably not be a problem because they both belong to the same Sitefinity version (10.0), so there should be no schema changes between them.
It would be a problem though, if you try to run a 9.2 build on a 10.0 database.

Answer (score 2):

I know its late. Maybe still can help someone else. Execute this query. Its works for me.

```
update [DB_NAME].[dbo].[sf_schema_vrsns]
set version_number = 6410
where version_number = 6421

update [DB_NAME].[dbo].[sf_schema_vrsns]
set [assembly] = REPLACE([assembly],'10.0.6421.0','10.0.6410.0')
where [assembly] like '%10.0.6421.0%';
```